# Dual boot W7 and W10 second partition not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot, gpt, dualboot

Disk type is **GPT**

I have installed Windows 7 then made full backup using Aomei Backupper

Then wiped disk and installed Windows 10 and made full backup using Aomei Bacupper.

Then wiped disk and restored Windows 7 Backup and split partition into two and restored Windows 10 partition into second partition.

Then using EasyBCD i added second OS as entry point for BCD however when i restart my computer and select Windows 10 at countdown i am getting error.

How do i boot to Windows 10 now?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When i select boot Windows 10 option i get this.
[image]

If i select boot Windows 10 and press F8 i get to menu.
[image]

Comment: We cannot help you without your BCD. We also need to know the partitions GUIDs

Comment: Which error are you getting? What exactly do you see when booting (photo)?

Comment: @Ramhound i updated post if you need more info please do explain how can i get it.

Comment: I would still like to know what exactly do you see when booting (photo) and which error you are getting when booting Windows 10. My theory at the moment is that you have installed Windows 7 with the BIOS set to Legacy mode, then installed the EFI version of Windows 10, which means that Windows 10 cannot boot in Legacy mode.

Comment: @harrymc updated.

Comment: The 0xc000000e error on boot means a corrupted Boot Configuration Data. Try in an elevated CMD to run : `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. Question: Did you change anything in the BIOS while installing these two Windows versions? Are both versions 64-bit?

Comment: @harrymc both are x64 and installed as GPT. my bcd and boot partition is left from Windows 7 installation for windows 10 i only restored files on partition D:

Comment: @RomanToasov `BootRec` is in all WinPE/WinRE images

Comment: You didn’t provide everything I requested.

Comment: @Ramhound its beyond my knowledge what you asking  can you tell me how to get that info? [bcd backup](https://www.upload.ee/files/13982008/BCD_Backup.html)

harrymc this is result i get running [bootrec](https://i.postimg.cc/jKRB10QP/8.jpg) still same error